# how to get the list value from list of dict

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's say I have one list below, which consist of `dictionary`. I wanted to get the key with list of combined value for same key.

```
abc=[{'sub':'1','id':'1'},{'sub':'1','id':'2'},{'sub':'2','id':'3'}]
```

exxpected output:

```
[{'sub':1,'id':[1,2]},{'sub':2,id:[3]}]
```

Comment: Try to use `defaultdict` from collections module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly let me know if this what you were anticipating.

```
result = (pd.DataFrame(abc).groupby(['sub'])
       .agg(list)
       .reset_index()
       .to_dict('r'))
```

Output:

```
[{'sub': '1', 'id': ['1', '2']}, {'sub': '2', 'id': ['3']}]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. Please take a moment to read [answer]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!